# running external process from scala using sbt ! operator under Windows

Tags: scala, batch-file, sbt, external-process, exitstatus

I have the following two lines in my scala program

```
val success:Int = ("d:\\program.bat" !)
println("started "+success)
```

program.bat looks like  this

```
@echo off
start "" "d:\notepad.exe"
echo DONE
```

the program actually starts tomcat server, but it is all the same for firefox, notepad etc... so I simplified this to notepad.exe

I would like to start notepad and see "started 0".

The problem is that the code stops at the first line and doesnt print "started 0" until I close notepad

The last line of the program.bat is

```
echo DONE
```

and DONE is the last thing printed out before the execution stops (so I assume it doesnt stop inside program.bat).

I tried putting EXIT /B 0 at the end of my program.bat script but it doesn't change anything.

I heard it works fine under linux (using program.sh of course).

Any suggestions how to REALLY detach the notepad from program.bat and return 0?

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is to be expected, because the `!` operator returns the exit code of the invoked program - which implies, that the program has to terminate before the exit code can be returned. Quoting an example from the [`process` docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.package):

```
import scala.sys.process._

// This uses ! to get the exit code
def fileExists(name: String) = Seq("test", "-f", name).! == 0

// This uses !! to get the whole result as a string
val dirContents = "ls".!!

// This "fire-and-forgets" the method, which can be lazily read through
// a Stream[String]
def sourceFilesAt(baseDir: String): Stream[String] = {
  val cmd = Seq("find", baseDir, "-name", "*.scala", "-type", "f")
  cmd.lines
}
```

If you are interested in the exit code but want your Scala program to make progress in the mean time, for example, print the output of the invoked program, you could use `ProcessBuilder.hasExitValue` to find out when the exit code is available.

Comment: thanks for the answer! This is a useful knowledge. But what I actually want to achieve is to make program.bat "fire and forget" the notepad rather than scala program "fire and forget" program.bat. So do I get it right that program.bat do not terminate (although it prints out DONE) until the process it started terminates? Can I force it to terminate and not wait for notepad to terminate?

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your post then. If you run `program.bat` in on the shell you'll that it does fire-and-forget Notepad. However, the process started by Scala only terminates once all child processes have terminated, which includes the fired-and-forgotten Notepad process.